# Facebook fanpage .ics link for upcoming events does not work

Tags: wordpress, facebook, icalendar

I own a personal Facebook account and a second Facebook account for a bands fanpage. I want to integrate the facebook events via .ics subscription to my wordpress calendar.

Therefor I logon to Facebook with my personal account (or with my bands account, it makes no difference), then I go to one specific event and click on the "..." button next to share and then I choose "export event"

[image: export event]

and after that I have the link for all upcoming events.

[image: .ics link for upcoming events]

When I subscribe to this URL e.g. in macOS Calendar, no events are delivered...

Does anybody know whats going wrong here?

Comment: File a bug with Facebook

Comment: @WizKid what do you exactly mean? Do you mean that i should ask Facebook directly for support? Do they offer direct support or only community based?

Comment: Right now your question is not programming related... Maybe could be on-topic on [webapps.se], but check their FAQ first

Comment: Are your events public? if not, they won't appear.

Comment: Typed the URL from your screenshot, and got an ICS file containing the info for the event … Not sure what exactly the problem is here?

Comment: @anmari yes, the events are public

Comment: @CBroe what happens, if you signup to this URL webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=100000597561645&key=AQBni-e8euLnotXt in a calendar client e.g. google calendar or macOS calendar? I don't see any events...

Comment: I also tried "https" instead of "webcal" in the url because this was mentioned in another forum but this also didn't help

Comment: @brasofilo i ask this question here because i want to implement the ics-subscription to my wordpress site, so it is web development, which is also a kind of programming, isn't it?

Comment: I see one event now from that url  (with https://) "Summer Party zur Shopping Kultur Nacht" on 20180803.   Perhaps FB slow to update ics? or event is now public?

Comment: Hi @anmari, i don't know that event on 20180308. It is not visible on my Event-List on the Facebook Site https://www.facebook.com/pg/kapelle.josefmenzl/events/?ref=page_internal ...

I also don't know how to enter private events on a Facebook fanpage... So i just enter it and i think all of them are public as they should also be visible, when you visit the page...

Comment: If you open the url you advised above ie: https://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=100000597561645&key=AQBni-e8euLnotX in text editor then that is the only event in the ics file. See https://imgur.com/a/NGKRoeD.  I'm not a FB expert, perhaps it is the wrong url ?  It says hosted by https://www.facebook.com/Discothek.Platzl.Bodenmais/ by has your name as the calendar name.  Seems to me this a facebook or facebook app usage problem?

Comment: hi @anmari, thank you for this information: this is a complete wrong event and URL. It seems that Facebook is generating a complete wrong ICS-URL which does not point to my events! I think i have to adress this issue to Facebook that they should check this bug! Thank you!